# How to prove that $||M\vec{x}|| \leq c||\vec{x}||$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What are some hints for how I could go about showing that for any $m$ x $n$ matrix M, there exists a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the following holds: $||M\vec{x}|| \leq c||\vec{x}||$? I know that I am supposed to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, specifically that for $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$, for a dimension $k$, then $|| \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} || \leq ||x||$ $||x||$. I know that multiplying $M$ and $\vec{x}$ will result in a $m$ dimensional vector, but wouldn't I need a $n$ dimensional vector in order to use the theorem?

Comment: Hint: $|ax+by|\le \max\{|a|,|b|\}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c' := \max_{i=1,\dotsc,n} \|M e_i\|$. Then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
 \|M x\|
 = \left\| \sum_{i=1}^n x_i M e_i \right\|
 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \|M e_i\|
 \leq c' \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{|x_i|}_{\leq \|x\|}
 \leq n c' \|x\|,
$$
so we can take $c := nc' = n\max_{i=1,\dotsc,n} \|M e_i\|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=Mx$. Then
$$
v_i=\sum_{j=1}^nM_{ij}x_j\implies||v||^2=\sum_i\left(\sum_jM_{ij}x_j\right)^2.
$$
By C-S, we have
$$
\left(\sum_jM_{ij}x_j\right)^2\leq\left(\sum_jM_{ij}^2\right)\left(\sum_jx_j^2\right)=\left(\sum_jM_{ij}^2\right)||x||^2.
$$
It follows that
$$
||v||^2\leq\left[\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{j=1}^nM_{ij}^2\right)\right]||x||^2.
$$
It remains to label the expression in the square brackets above as $c^2$.

If $M=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1x' \\ \cdots \\ \alpha_mx'\end{pmatrix}$ for scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$, then the inequality above becomes an equality.